# Unable to Download App - iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to export distribution build for push notification testing purpose using distribution certificate.
So I have chosen way for *Save for Ad Hoc Deployment*.

[image]

But I was getting **Unable to Download App** error:

[image]

I was doing same way before but from last 3 to 4 days, same way exporting process not working for me. Don't know what is happening wrong with me.

Here is details about architecture:[image]

Its not like, I was doing push notification first or build exporting first time.
I have enough experience with this process.

Only **Save for Ad Hoc Deployment** mode my build was not working if I choose any other mode say **Save for Development Deployment** then its working perfectly.
But in this mode, I can't able to test push notification.

So please give some guidance to solve this point. If you require more information about this then ask anytime, I am available to provide that.

Comment: Please give me some suggestion into this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time spend, I can able to solve this project so sharing here so for same purpose other users not share their time.

I think after update from Apple side, if you want to install distribution build within your iPhone then you must require to setup adhoc distribution profile.

[image]

Before we are using App Store provisioning profile to run within iPhone as well.

At export time you require to select this option.[image]

By this way you can run distribution build within your iOS device and test push notification.

Above point changed recently so I have made this point clear to other users.